# Dowloading multiple file using Python

Tags: python

I have a list of file id, about 100 id, and I need to download them using python. The URL for downloading them is the same just the id comes at end of the URL. For example for id = 44444

```
   Request URL: http://.../../..?..=false&id=44444
```

Also we have to login to the web site by user name and password. Since I'm new to python I don't have any idea. How I can do this task?

Answer (score 0):

If there is no API you can use you should use a web scraping library.

Comment: can you tell me how I can use? @Vulwsztyn